# Removing whitespace from config without installing any packages

Tags: python, html, config

I have a config file that sets the port for the HTTP to run, I would like to allow/replace whitespaces around the equal sign to allow the code to run normally but have no idea how to program it. Due to me sending this code to someone else and wanting to use virtualenv I don't want to install any packages but fix this with python.

example.conf

```
port = 8000
```

example.py

```
conf = subprocess.run(["grep", "port=", "example.conf"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
if b"=" not in conf.stdout:
    print("Could not read configuration file `example.conf`")
    sys.exit(1)
port = conf.stdout.split(b"=")[1]
```

That's pretty much it. I am not very experienced with this type of code so it could be badly written. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `s.replace(" = ", "=")`..?

Comment: There is a space between `port` and `=`, so I doubt the grep would return a result.

Comment: @Jay what should I use instead of grep then? I need there to be a space between the port and =.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code example above (and with some assumptions made):

```
port = None
with open('example.conf', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if "port =" in line:
            port = line.split("=")[1].strip()
            break
if port:
    print(port)
else:
    print('No port number found')
```